# utf-8 on web page translating some characters

Tags: html, text, character, content-type

I seem to have encountered a weird behaviour with my HTML page, where it can 
display some Chinese characters only and some are tagged as ??

I have already changed the HTTP header to utf-8 
Content-Type: `"text/html; charset=utf-8"`

�?��?好

Question is why only some Chinese characters can be shown and some not??

Edit :-

I have dug deeper in the issue and there is two parts in the code. 
There is a function in the code to encode strings to cp1252 encoding on this string

before encoding :-

```
<pre>
<font size=\"2\">\x{e6}\x{99}\x{9a}\x{e5}\x{ae}\x{89} &nbsp;</font>
</pre>
```

after encoding :-

[image]

Then I tested by changing the encoding to iso-8859-1 and everything is showing fine. My question now is why is that ?? I'm assuming cp1252 is older and does not support some utf-8 encodings ??

Thank You.

Comment: How is file being encoded? Also UTF-8?

Comment: Can you paste some examples of the names of the symbols that are working and those that are not? I would guess some are not encompassed in the content type, but seems odd

Comment: The HTTP header is like those flags you find in tourist leaflets that tell you what language the information is written on. You have to print the right flag but using a different one won't translate the text.

Comment: *"Question: why...?"* – In a nutshell: because you're not handling encoding correctly. If you need more help to actually handle encodings correctly, we'd need more information about what exactly you're doing that causes this problem right now.

Comment: hi thanks, I have updated the post with my latest findings